# How do I prevent this prolog code, that replaces elements in a list, from giving an additional output?

Tags: loops, prolog

### The issue:

Input:

```
placeRedBlocks(3, X), replaceX(X, 0, 3, r, R).
```

Expected Output:

```
R = [r, r, r],
X = [b, b, b]
```

Real Output:

```
R = [r, r, r],
X = [b, b, b]
R = [b, r, r],
X = [b, b, b]
```

### Explanation:

This prolog code takes a list of values and replaces the designated values and returns it into another list.

```
replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):- 
%  write('a'),
  I > -1,
%  write('b'),
  NI is I-1,
%  write('c'),
  replace(T, NI, X, R), !.
replace(L, _, _, L).

replaceX(A,_,0,_,A):- !.
replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
%  write('A'),
  replace(Line,Index,Elm,BLine),
%  write('B'),
  Index1 is Index+1,
%  write('C'),
  NumElm1 is NumElm-1,
%  write('D'),
  replaceX(BLine,Index1,NumElm1,Elm,NLine).
```

In `replaceX`:

`Line` is the list you are trying to replace the values in. `Index` is the position in the list where you start replacing values. `NumElm` is the number of elements you are replacing in total. `Elm` is the character or number that replaces the other values in the list. `NLine` is the list where the output will go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: comment out the last line in `replace/4` (or add a cut to the first line).

Longer answer: the result is built-up from the end, so when you get to the case where `I` is zero, you have the result up to the (sequentially) first element to replace, which is handled by the first line in `replace/4`, but then the last line also succeeds, giving you an output where the first element is not replaced.

Bonus: cuts are ugly. If you do not pattern-match you do not need more than one clause. This is better:

```
replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
  ( NumElm > 0 ->
    replace(Line,Index,Elm,BLine),
    Index1 is Index + 1,
    NumElm1 is NumElm - 1,
    replaceX(BLine,Index1,NumElm1,Elm,NLine)
  ; NLine = Line ).
replace([H|T],I,X,[H|R]):- 
  ( I > -1 ->
    NI is I - 1,
    replace(T,NI,X,R)
  ; R = T ).
replace([],_,_,[]).
```